# Start Workflow via JS gives error "Value cannot be null"

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, workflow, spservices

Hi I am attempting to start an SP 2010 workflow using Jquery SP Services but i seem to be getting a response 500 Value cannot be null. There is not supposed to be an initiation form yet when i manually start the workflow via link i get an infopath form with just Start Cancel buttons as i have no parameters. Can anyone spot an issue?

```
 $().SPServices({
            operation: "StartWorkflow",
            item: "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com" + fileRef,
            templateId: "{463231b0-e608-44e1-ae9f-57af1832565d}",
            workflowParameters: "<root><data></data></root>"
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the first example on the [StartWorkflow](https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/core/web-services/Workflow/StartWorkflow.html) documentation, it looks like your workflowParameters should be `"<root />"`.

I think by having `<Data></Data>` in there it is expecting that there be a parameter in there and is erroring out when there's nothing in there.

500 errors are Server level errors, so it may be valuable to log the `item` url to make sure the fileRef variable is pulling in a correct URL also.